# Where can I find all list of style properties supported by react js?

Tags: reactjs, properties, documentation, styling

something like this https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet

bonus if there are properties for everything, not just styling. and anything else like this that would be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ **THIS IS FOR REACT NATIVE** ]

Yes, in the react native documentation you can find all the available style properties for the components

Link : https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props, https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props

Answer (score 1):

Example in CSS:

```
background-color: '#ffffff';
```

In React.js:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
```

React.js uses CSS rules, so you just find in CSS
[CSS Cheat sheet](https://adam-marsden.co.uk/css-cheat-sheet)

[Another document](https://devdocs.io/css/)